# All literals implied by a set of horn clauses

Tags: lo.logic, terminology

What is the name of this problem: given a set of Horn clauses (in fact just definite clauses and facts), find the set of literals which can be deduced from it. E.g. given $\{a, a \Rightarrow b, b \wedge c \Rightarrow d\}$, output $\{a, b\}$.

Comment: I omit goal clauses because they never change the output.

Comment: It's called finding a minimal model of a set of Horn clauses. (Or "the", because there's only one.)

Comment: or it can be seen as the backbone of the formula

Comment: @RaduGRIGore: make that an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called finding a minimal model of a Horn formula.

This model is unique because the intersection of two models of a Horn formula is itself a model. In fact, [Horn, On sentences which are true of direct unions of algebras, 1951] proved the following: A boolean function can be expressed as a conjunction of Horn clauses if and only if its set of models is closed under intersection.

Answer (score 2):

It's finding a closure of a set of formulae. In abstract logic, it's what a Tarskian consequence operator does: $Cn(\Gamma)=\{\varphi : \Gamma \vdash \varphi \}$

Comment: The question asked for the literals, the closure under the consequence operator includes Boolean combinations of literals (for the given example it includes $d\vee b$).

Comment: It's trivial to obtain the subset of literals from $Cn(\Gamma)$.

Comment: That's true, but it does demonstrate that the name of this concept is not the closure.

Comment: @Max Right. The appropriate name is "finding a model that satisfies the formulae" (as suggested above).

Comment: @Atamiri, In addition to a different name, there are differences in terms of complexity, decidability etc. when you start considering these problems for richer logics, so it's not useful to think of it in terms of closure.

Comment: @VijayD To get all implied literals you need a closure. There are papers on transitive closures to build up models. Generally decidability won't be different.